# Angular ngbDatePicker - ng touch validation not work

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Hey I use ngbDataPicker with other inputs of ng bootstrap.
All the inputs work fine but when I touch/click on the date picker the validation don't work just after I check date and remove it again the validation work.
in other inputs, when I touch the inputs the validation start work.

What the problem with the ngbDatePicker?

Template:

```
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="datepicker">
              <input ngbDatepicker class="form-control" placeholder="בחירת תאריך" name="dp" #d="ngbDatepicker"
                formControlName="deadline" required>
              <button class="calendar-btn" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Ts:

```
constructor(private _flowService: FlowsService,
                private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
                private _datePickerConfig: NgbDatepickerConfig) {

}   ngOnInit() {
        this._setupFormBuilder();
    }

 private _setupFormBuilder() {
        this.createFlowForm = this._formBuilder.group({
            deadline: ['', Validators.required],
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you are mixing two "validations": Angular and bootstrap.js Angular, when some control is invalid add the class **ng-invalid**, and when is touched the class **ng-touched** to controls, see [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes), bootstrap.js add the class 'is-invalid' if some is invalid.

REMEMBER: ng-bootstrap need bootstrap.css but **NOT* bootstrap.js or jquery

Using only Angular you only need add the class (copy and paste class of bootstrap invalid)

```
  .form-control.ng-invalid.ng-touched
{
    border-color:#dc3545;
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + .75rem);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='12' height='12' fill='none' stroke='%23dc3545' viewBox='0 0 12 12'%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='6' r='4.5'/%3e%3cpath stroke-linejoin='round' d='M5.8 3.6h.4L6 6.5z'/%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='8.2' r='.6' fill='%23dc3545' stroke='none'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right calc(.375em + .1875rem) center;
    background-size: calc(.75em + .375rem) calc(.75em + .375rem);
}
.form-control.ng-invalid.ng-touched:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem rgba(220,53,69,.25);
}
```

other option is use [ngClass]

```
<input [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':model?.invalid && model?.touched}"...>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7jnbdu?file=app%2Fdatepicker-popup.ts)

Comment: Thanks Bro, My problem was in the button but thanks to you I see where the problem.